# Observable Collection issue in ListBox with DisplayMemberPath

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<UsageItem> MyItems;` :

**EDIT :**

```
public class UsageItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    int _ChargesLeft;
    public int ChargesLeft
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChargesLeft;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (_ChargesLeft != value)
            {
                _ChargesLeft = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ChargesLeft");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
        }
    public Consummable(string name, int charges)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ChargesLeft = charges;
    }


    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            if (ChargesLeft > 1)
            {
                return Name + " " + ChargesLeft + "charges";
            }
            else
            {
                return Name + " " + ChargesLeft + "charge";
            }
        }
    }
    public override void use(Hero hero)
    {
        if(this.ChargesLeft >= 1)
        {
            this.ChargesLeft--;
        }else{
        //Will remove this UsageItem from my ObservableCollection
        ...
       }
    }

}
```

I've bound my `Collection` to a `ListBox` :

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxBackPack"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"/>
```

I have a button that when clicked call the `use` function on my `SelectedItem`, it will decrease the value my ChargesLeft Field or remove the object.

If I click the button while my ChargesLeft value is <= 1 it will remove my Item from my Collection, and my ListBox will be updated as expected, no problem.
But If I use an item with a ChargesLeft >= 1, then I will decrease my field and so in consequence change my DisplayName.
As I still change my Collection I would expect a `CollectionChanged` Event to fire and my ListBox to be refreshed and display the new `DisplayValue` of the item, but it does not happen, the `ListBox` keep displaying the old `DisplayValue`.
At this moment if I manually do a `Listbox.Items.Refresh()` (Binded it on a button for testing) it will refresh and correctly display the right `DisplayValue`, but I can't call this function from my `ViewModel`, as it has no knowledge of my `ListBox`

How can I do to automatically force the refresh of my `ListBox` when I modify an item ?

Comment: implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `UsageItem` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CollectionChanged` is raised when you add or delete an item or clear the whole collection. Your `UsageItem` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` itself to track changes in collection items.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

> Note
>
> To fully support transferring data values from binding source objects to binding targets, each object in your collection that supports bindable properties must implement an appropriate property changed notification mechanism such as the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

**Update**
See a working example (I used Prism but that doesn't matter):

**UsageItem.cs:**

```
public class UsageItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                RaisePropertyChanged("DisplayName");
            }
        }
    }

    int _ChargesLeft;
    public int ChargesLeft
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChargesLeft;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ChargesLeft != value)
            {
                _ChargesLeft = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ChargesLeft");
                RaisePropertyChanged("DisplayName");
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
    public UsageItem(string name, int charges)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.ChargesLeft = charges;
    }


    public string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            if (ChargesLeft > 1)
            {
                return Name + " " + ChargesLeft + "charges";
            }
            else
            {
                return Name + " " + ChargesLeft + "charge";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _title = "Prism Unity Application";
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<UsageItem>();
        Items.Add(new UsageItem("Bob", 1));
        Items.Add(new UsageItem("Bill", 2));
        Items.Add(new UsageItem("Joe", 3));

        CurrentItem = Items[0];

        UseCommand = new DelegateCommand(Use);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<UsageItem> Items { get; private set; }

    private UsageItem _currentItem;
    public UsageItem CurrentItem
    {
        get { return _currentItem; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _currentItem, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand UseCommand { get; private set; }
    private void Use()
    {
        if (CurrentItem.ChargesLeft >= 1)
        {
            CurrentItem.ChargesLeft--;
        }
        else
        {
            //Will remove this UsageItem from my ObservableCollection
            Items.Remove(CurrentItem);
            CurrentItem = Items[0];
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="UsageLeft.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Command="{Binding UseCommand}" Content="Use" />
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I just implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` (see edit) but still observe the same behavior.  
I can see the PropertyEvent fire with ChargesLeft as parameter, but the `ListBox` still won't update unless I do it manually

Comment: @Belterius Your code obviously can't work as shown above, the constructor has a different name than a class, the override methods imply that it's a subclass, and the `use` method clearly doesn't belong to the class.

Comment: @Belterius Seems like you need to add `RaisePropertyChanged("DisplayName");` calls to setters of all properties that change DisplayName. See the updated answer.

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you very much.  And I indeed modified quite a bit my code to only keep the parts relevant to my problem, I don't think it would have been useful to keep the mainsclass, I missed to delete the overrides to keep it coherent tho.